# Почему не отображаеться merge коммит?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-branch, git-flow

У меня есть две ветки, одна дефолтная "master" и другая "Feature" которая идёт от "master". Если я создаю пару коммитов в "Feature" и потом пишу `git merge Feature` и потом пишу `git log --graph` то вижу как ветка слилась в "master" по линиям сбоку (картинка №1). Если я же сделаю наоброт - создам пару коммитов в ветке "master" и напишу `git merge master` то я не увижу слияния, да коммиты появились от мастер ветки, но нет коммита под слияние (картинка №2). Даже если я напишу `git log --merges` то я увижу всего один коммит - первый (картинка №3). Почему так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не очень понятно, что именно у вас происходит, но судя по некоторым деталям это похоже на `--ff-only` vs. `--no-ff`. Попробуйте эти ключи в различных вариантах слияния и расскажите об опыте.

Comment: @0andriy спасибо, если я использую слияние с ключём `--no-ff` - то создаётся коммит и сообщение к нему.

Мне не очень понятно до сих пор почему только при слиянии в `master` ветку создаёться merge-commit и прочее, а если наоборот - то нет. В любом случае спасибо =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На втором скрине в третьей строке написано «Fast-forward» — это значит что ветка master оказалась прямым потомком ветки Feature и git просто перенёс «указатель» на ветку.

Если всё-таки хочется что бы даже в таком случае создался merge-коммит, то надо использовать флаг `--no-ff`.

Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: автор вопроса уже ответил на свой вопрос, а вы его ответ ничем не дополнили

Answer (score 0):

Помогла установка ключа `--no-ff`